# Using html5 history in place of hash urls to restore the history of the user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, history.js, html5-history

We have a single page application that loads results based on query string.

The query string looks like:
?city=Delhi&pn=1

The SPA has different sections on the same webpage. When user navigates to those sections, we maintain history using hash changes. For example:
?city=Delhi&pn=1#sort     : Show sort parameter section of the SPA.
?city=Delhi&pn=1#filters  : Show filter section of the SPA.

We are now planning to drop maintaining history using hash changes in the url and instead start using html5 history api.

How can these hash be replaces and same functionality performed using history plugin?

I tried with a + sign, for example (?city=Delhi&pn=1+sort). But looks like user cannot bookmark this and page would break since api doesn't handle + sign. + sign is taken as space in ajax api request.

What are other possibilities to handle it elegantly?

Answer (score 1):

The standard means to encode the data on a query string is to add another key=value pair.

```
?city=Delhi&pn=1&sort=true
```

---

Note that if you are using the history API then you should have server side code capable of generating *the same view* that the JavaScript would generate.

e.g.

1. User arrives on `/` and gets the homepage delivered by the server
2. User follows a link to `/?city=Delhi&pn=1&sort=true` and Ajax transforms the page into another page.
3. User bookmarks link
4. User goes away
5. User comes back another day to their bookmark and the server (not JavaScript) builds `/?city=Delhi&pn=1&sort=true`
6. User follows another link and JS kicks in

This means that:

- The site performs faster on initial load. You don't have to load the homepage and then wait for JS to make additional requests to transform it into the page you initially asked for.
- It is good food for search engines
- It continues to work [when JS fails](http://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html).

Comment: In our scenario, I dont think we need to generate same view from server side code. I think it would do if i simply ignore these additional parameters on server side. We are fine if user paste such url and results are loaded ignoring it with only original query string parameters.

Comment: "In our scenario, I dont think we need to generate same view from server side code." — Then there is no point in using the history API instead of hash bangs.

Comment: we have a reason for that-since its a search page with multiple different filters which user can apply one by one and we want to provide functionality for browser back so that he can remove filters one by one through browser back. I agree this could be done by hashbang too but it would be completely manual while history api would make it easier for us. Please correct me if wrong.

Comment: You can use the hashchange event. AFAIK that gives you as much as the history API would.

Comment: I have done it for one level filter applying, for example by placing #filter but how would i do that for each nested level for all filters. I will have to append #filterName each time.

Comment: Structure the data however you like. Comma separated or whatever.

Comment: Why do all that when we can record changes in query string and track them through history api without any such extra effort. All work would be done by the changes in query string itself and we have to just push it.